# How to animate inserts and removes in a container with justify-content?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, transition, flexbox

Using the flexbox `justify-content` property, elements can be distributed evenly in their container. However, I want to animate their positions when a new element is inserted or an existing one is removed.

I only managed to animate the height of the elements so far. However, there is a jump at the end of the animation since the gaps around the removed element that got animated to `height: 0` vanish. Analogously, when inserting an element there is a jump at the beginning of the animation.

Is it possible to make an animation from end to end with `justify-content`? Here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/sfan6yv2/3/) to play with. Using CSS transition is preferred.

Comment: Basically... NO. There is no start and end value to animate. It's just on or off.

Comment: I don't mean to turn off the property. I'd like to smoothly add and remove elements.

Comment: Hmm...frankly I'm doubtful. It might take some digging into the spec to see what parts are actually animatable but It just doesn't feel like this is an easy solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that the behavior you are getting is the expected one.

In the very same instant that `card.remove()` is executed the flexbox `justify-content` property need to adjust the gaps around the removed element (as you said). And, as *Paulie D* has pointed out, there is nothing to animate about.

The only solution I can think about is to skip the *flex* thing and use javascript to create the necessary gaps among the *card* elements.

Here I leave the snippet:

```js
var animation_time = 500;
var column_height = $('.column').height();
var cards_height = $('.card').height();

var cards_number;
var cards_total_height;
var space_to_be_distributed;
var placeholder_height;

function updateSizes(cards_number)
{
    cards_total_height = cards_number * cards_height;
    space_to_be_distributed = column_height - cards_total_height;
    placeholder_height = space_to_be_distributed / (cards_number + 1);
}

updateSizes($('.card').length);

$('.placeholder').height(placeholder_height);

$(document).on('click', '.card', function () {
    var card = $(this);
    card.animate({height: 0, opacity: 0}, animation_time, function () {
     card.remove(); 
    });
    updateSizes($('.card').length - 1);
    var placeholder  = card.next();
    $('.placeholder').not(placeholder).animate({height: placeholder_height}, animation_time);
    placeholder.animate({height: 0}, animation_time, function () {
     placeholder.remove();
        updateSizes($('.card').length);
        $('.placeholder').animate({height: placeholder_height}, animation_time);
    });
});

$('a').click(function () {
    var card = $('<div class="card">');
    card.css({opacity: 0, height: 0})
        .appendTo('.column')
        .animate({height: 25, opacity: 1}, animation_time);        
 var placeholder = $('<div class="placeholder">');
    placeholder.css({height: 0})
     .appendTo('.column');
    updateSizes($('.card').length);
    $('.placeholder').animate({height: placeholder_height}, animation_time);
});
```

```css
body, html, .column {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.column {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    background: navy;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card {   
    height: 25px;
    width: 100px;
    background: grey;
}
.placeholder {   
    height: 25px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="column">
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
</div>
<a href="#">Add card</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps!

EDIT - I made the following changes in the code:

- I change the fiddle for a SO snippet.
- I forced an update of elements size at the end of the animation (in case you click to remove an element before the last one has been completely removed)
- I change the size of the elementes to adapt it to the (small) SO snippet window.

Comment: Thank you. I know the behavior I see is expected :). I'm going to solve this by having invisible ghost objects in the flex layout for all cards. Then I can position the cards absolutely on top of everything and update their positions towards their corresponding ghosts every time step.

Comment: Glad it helped! The gost objects solution can be computationally expensive (not sure) but also maybe smother. Actually, as you could see, I needed to add a `overflow: hidden` to the _column_ class.